# IndexError but I do not know why its being thrown

Tags: python, pandas, index-error

IndexError is thrown.

I am still very new to coding, so I am not really sure what is going wrong here. I know that an IndexError is thrown when you are trying to index into a value which has none. (The DataFrame below just looks akward due to the space given.)

```
def get_rb_data(data, team):
    return np.asarray(data[data['Tm'] == team])[1]
data.columns.get_loc('Tm')
data.head()

1

          Player    Tm  Age Pos G   GS  Att Yds TD  1D  Succ%   Lng Y/A Y/G Fmb
1   Derrick Henry*  TEN 28  RB  16  16  349 1538    13  65  46.7    56  4.4 96.1    6
2   Josh Jacobs*+   LVR 24  RB  17  17  340 1653    12  93  57.4    86  4.9 97.2    3
3   Nick Chubb* CLE 27  RB  17  17  302 1525    12  69  50.0    41  5.0 89.7    1
4   Saquon Barkley* NYG 25  RB  16  16  295 1312    10  62  47.5    68  4.4 82.0    1
5   Najee Harris    PIT 24  RB  17  17  272 1034    7   45  46.0    36  3.8 60.8    3



print(data.index)

RangeIndex(start=1, stop=379, step=1)




fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), facecolor='white')
# Add subplots
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='polar', facecolor='#ededed')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='polar', facecolor='#ededed')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223, projection='polar', facecolor='#ededed')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='polar', facecolor='#ededed')
# Adjust space between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8, wspace=0.5)
# Get RB data
sf_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'SFO')
sea_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'SEA')
ari_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'ARI')
lar_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'LAR')
# Plot RB data
ax1 = create_radar_chart(ax1, angles, lar_data, team_colors['LAR'])
ax2 = create_radar_chart(ax2, angles, ari_data, team_colors['ARI'])
ax3 = create_radar_chart(ax3, angles, sea_data, team_colors['SEA'])
ax4 = create_radar_chart(ax4, angles, sf_data, team_colors['SFO'])
plt.show()

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[142], line 10
      8 plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8, wspace=0.5)
      9 # Get RB data
---> 10 sf_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'SFO')
     11 sea_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'SEA')
     12 ari_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'ARI')

Cell In[139], line 2, in get_rb_data(data, team)
      1 def get_rb_data(data, team):
----> 2     return np.asarray(data[data['Tm'] == team])[1]

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I tried to copy some code and change it from a quarterback radar mapping program to runningback radar mapping program, however in the helper function *def _rb_data() it initially runs fine, but when called in the next cell, it throws the IndexError, even though I checked and data indeed has an index.

I expected for the program to run at the end and plot a radar chart.

Comment: Why does yor code sample show ```plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8, wspace=0.5)
# Get RB data
sf_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'SFO')``` and your error shows ```plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8, wspace=0.5)
# Get QB data
sf_data = get_rb_data(data_radar_filtered, 'SFO')```?

Comment: It was a typo from when I was following the guide. Ill edit the code after I saved and renamed

Comment: You're specifically asking for the index 1 in your function:  return np.asarray(data[data['Tm'] == team])[1]   That's why if it's of length 0, you can't access item 1.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Jesse! I did some morphing of my Dataframe, which ended up changing the name of it, when I instead pointed to my most recent dataframe and index [0] the error resolved. New code is as follows - def get_rb_data(data_radar_400Yds, team):
    return np.asarray([data_radar_400Yds['Tm'] == team])[0]
print(data_radar_400Yds.columns.get_loc('Tm'))
data_radar_400Yds.head()